# Styling a md-grid-list

Tags: angular-material

I am using an Angular Material grid list to display around 500 - 1000 items. I am having some trouble styling it to my liking. Here is what the grid list looks like now:

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-xs="1" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="4" md-cols-gt-md="6"
              md-row-height="16:9"
              md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px">

  <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="orgOrder in vm.orgOrders | filter: query1"
                style="background: #f5f5f5"
                layout-align="center center"
                ng-click="vm.addOrder(orgOrder)">
    <div layout="column">
      <div> {{orgOrder.orderNumber}}</div>
      <!--<div> {{orgOrder.reqExFact | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</div>-->
    </div>

  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

[image: my awesome grid list]

Here is what I would like to do:

1. My grid titles(items) are a way too big for a single line, how do I make my grid titles fit the data in them? Setting the md-row-height="fit" makes it look like this.
   [image]
2. At the moment my grid-list is several 'scrolls' long. I would like to put it into a container and add a scroll to it. Warping my grid-list or grid title in an md-container sets their height to 0.

Let me know if you need to see any more of my code.

here is a jsfiddle similar to my code:https://jsfiddle.net/rakshak/6tjgbb85/

I would like the grid titles(items) to fit the text in them and I would like to wrap a container around the entire grid list and have a overflow scroll bar instead of the entire window scrolling.

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle would be extremely helpful in solving your problem, could you post one up? I can think of a couple solutions, but I would like to get a look at what specifically you're asking about to be sure

Comment: Added a jsfiddle similar to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting md-row-height like `md-row-height="20px"` or `md-row-height="30px"` seems to address the height issues nicely. Nesting the grid inside of a fixed height div defined something like this:

```
.tileContainer {display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;}
```

will give you a scroll bar for the tiles.

I forked your plunker here: https://jsfiddle.net/uegLh6t4/

Comment: I am new web development, is setting fixed values like  md-row-height="20px" and height:100px; a good idea ? I was hoping there was some way to set a relative value.

Comment: The row height has to accommodate your text. There's nothing wrong with setting it to a fixed height that does that. You can set the div height based on a % or set it to a different fixed height based on the device.