# How to bind class in md-grid-tile?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an model as:

```
 tiles = [
    {text: 'One', cols: 1, rows: 1 , class: 'red-hours'}];
```

And I tried to display block with class

```
<md-grid-tile
    *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
    [colspan]="tile.cols"
    [rowspan]="tile.rows"
    [style.background]="tile.color">
    [class]="tile.class"
    {{tile.text}}
  </md-grid-tile>
```

Also how to insert custom content in each field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute binding for this. In my example, I only set the class. You can modify this to also set other properties

```
app.component.html:

<div   *ngFor="let tile of tiles" >
   <span  [attr.class] = "tile.class"> {{tile.text}}</span>
</div>

app.component.ts:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styles: ['.red {color: red};']
})


export class AppComponent {

  tiles = [
    {text: 'One', class: 'red'}];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain me how to style this grid by own css? Now when I inserted <div><div> it displayed by inline.Not as block

Comment: You can define your own styles for the div in the styles decorator. In your ts file:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styles: ['.yourownstyle {display: block};']
})

Comment: may be you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535181/styling-a-md-grid-list

.tileContainer {display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;}

Comment: Okay, thank you, also how to set default height for field? Except header fields?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attribute binding, consider using [`NgClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). This plunker shows a couple different options you have:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ePQGMYdKi2bStpMuqoUr?p=preview

```
<md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
  <md-grid-tile>1</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile [class.red-tile]="true">2</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile ngClass="red-tile">3</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile [ngClass]="'red-tile'">4</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```